# Blast markers hitting multistorey buildings

Tags: warhammer-40k

This has caused a large amount of discussion today and we couldn't find a suitable answer in the rule book. When a blast marker (not flamer template) hits a multistorey building, who gets hit? Is it everyone or is one level nominated. If possible, could you also provide a pointer to where the information is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of the rules, the blast would only hit the top floor. RAW in the current version blasts hit every floor. Many tournaments use 6th edition rules. For your local play group I would suggest picking one way and sticking with it, or at least deciding before the start of the game.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. At the club we've decided that you nominate the floor you're targeting when you fire the shot.

Comment: In the latest FAQ Games Workshop have confirmed this is the correct answer.